# Open bootstrap timepicker on click of link and add multiple times as tags

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have bootstrap datetimepicker which I would like to open on click of a link and add multiple times inside an input box as tags. How can I bind this to a link and can I have a button inside popup something like "add" to be able to select multiple times without closing and opening the popup. I am looking for something like below.

[image]

Currently, I have it opened on input box. Instead, I want it to be opened on click of anchor tag.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I am able to trigger the time pop on click of the link by making changes in the bootstap-datetimepicker.js itself like below. But I cannot still display the button.

```
    var a;
    a = h.element.is("input") ||  **h.element.is("a")** || h.options.inline ? h.element.data() : h.element.find("input").data(),
```

[image]

Comment: how if use bootstrap-datetimepicker "showClose" option, set to true, you can see close button in popup, and you can change close icon use "icons" option. 
for add time to input box you can use "dp.hide" event, when event called, get time value and add input input box.

i get option and event reference from this url http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try using those dp.* events, but how can I trigger this time popup on click of the link??

Comment: link you mean tag in input box? how if you add click event for tag, get tag value and call show() function bootstrap-datetimepicker and than set time value

Comment: I am able to achieve it by making changes in the bootstrap-datetimepicker  .js file itself as follows "a = h.element.is("input") ||  h.element.is("a") || h.options.inline ?". But, I am not able to display the close or any button. It looks like there is no support in this version of library. Any suggestions?

Comment: you use latest version of bootstrap datepicker?